# Expansion theorem or Poisson Summation Formula? - Basis of eigenfunctions gives rise to a Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, eigenfunctions

Does anyone could explain to me why in the Semiclassical's answer on the question [Wave kernel for the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ - Poisson Summation Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795763/wave-kernel-for-the-circle-mathbbs1-poisson-summation-formula), the basis gives a series of the form $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}a_0+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(a_k \cos kx+b_k \sin kx\right)$? Is it because of the Expansion theorem?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking why these are the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on the unit circle? Or why they form a complete basis for sufficiently smooth periodic functions?

Comment: @user7530 My apologie for the quality of the question. I mean I know that $\left\{\dfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi}},\dfrac1{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos x,\dfrac1{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin x,\dfrac1{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos 2x,\dfrac1{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin 2x,\cdots\right\}$ form a basis, but dont know why we could construct the Fourier series $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}a_0+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(a_k \cos kx+b_k \sin kx\right)$ with that basis, and that Fourier series is the same as $W(t,x,y)$ (wave kernel).

Comment: I'm still missing the actual question here: if $\{b_0, b_1, \ldots\}$ is a basis for a vector space $V$, then every element of $V$ can be expressed as $\sum a_i b_i$ for some coefficients $a_i$... that is all that is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question: if you agree that $\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos kx, \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin kx\right\}$ are a basis for the function space of $2\pi$-periodic functions, it follows immediately that any function in this space can be expressed as a linear combination of these basis functions (and the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are these coefficients).... that's just what it means for the functions to be a basis.

It's definitely worth learning more about Fourier series and Fourier transforms if you have the time, but if this is the part that is confusing you, forget it for now -- "Fourier" is a red herring here. The important steps for computing the wave kernel are

1. Computing that the eigenfunctions $\mu$ of the Laplacian $f'' = \lambda f$ with periodic boundary conditions are precisely the sines and cosines listed above;
2. The eigenvalue corresponding to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos kx$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin kx$ is $-k^2$;
3. The wave kernel is given by taking the weighted sum of products of eigenvfunctions, as written in the formula in the other post.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! However, why could we say that $W(t,x,y) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}a_0+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(a_k \cos kx+b_k \sin kx\right)$ ?

Comment: I think we have to use Poisson Summation Formula, because it makes the link between the wave kernel and the Fourier series.

Comment: Huh? That's not the wave kernel. You had the right formula in your own post, $W(t,x,y)= \sum_{k \geq 1} e^{it \sqrt{- \lambda_k}} \mu_k(x) \mu_k(y).$ Now plug in $\lambda$ and $\mu$ and use $\cos(x-y) = \cos x \cos y + \sin x \sin y$. Fourier series, Poisson summation, etc are all red herrings here.

Comment: Do you have an idea why if $$\sum_{k \geq 0} e^{it \sqrt{-\lambda_k}}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\sum_{k \geq 0} e^{it \sqrt{-\lambda_k}} \mu_k^2(x))dx= \sum_{k \geq 0} e^{it \sqrt{-\lambda_k}}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mu_k^2(x)dx,$$ then necessarily, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mu_k^2(x)dx=1$? This is come from the same question

Comment: The *definition* of $\mu_k$ is the $k$th eigenvalue of $\Delta$, normalized so that $\langle \mu_k, \mu_k\rangle = 1$.